# How to delete a particular data from database after certain time in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am designing an online bidding system. I want to remove the product details from the table name PRODUCT with fields pid,proname,price,pdesc. I am using sqlite3 with python. I am not clear how to use timestamp in this case.

Comment: Hi Humza.  Welcome to Stack.  I'm having trouble understanding your question.  You mention two different goals but it's unclear what is their connection.  You want to delete data from a database, and you want to learn how to utilize time stamps.  Perhaps this would be more clear as two separate questions?... Also paste the code you have so far when you can (with backticks ` `).

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't this be made in DB side as automated process? See: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html